# Align environment starts new page

Tags: equations, align, environments, page-breaking, blank-page

When I have equations within the align environment and there is no enough space on the page, the LaTeX starts a new page so that all equations are on the same page. This leaves (sometimes a huge) blank space on the previous page.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I mean, is there a way of having the aligned equations start on a page but end on the next page if there is no space available?

Comment: Adding \allowdisplaybreaks to your code should result in the expected output.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @leandriis, where it should be? Inside `align` or on preamble?

Comment: @Sigur not in the align, preamble normally but it's a local setting so you can have it mid-document if you need that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. So I suppose there is another command to turn it off in mid-document.

Comment: @Sigur not a documented one, no as normally you'd just use tex grouping but `\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000 ` would be the definition if there were a documented command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ow, everyday I learn something new. Thanks.